# Excel table : how can I change row and column?

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a table excel with one column and X rows.
4 various informations
example:

> row 1 2 3 4 = informations for 1
>   row 5 6 7 8 = information for 2

I would like to know how can I do to have these information by row instead of by column?

Example:

> paul
>   madrid
>   14
>   victor
>   canada
>   23
>   emilie
>   paris
>   18

and I Would like:

```
paul      Victor      Emilie
Madrid    Canada      Paris
14          23          18
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want change data only once, use Copy/Paste
[Switch (transpose) columns and rows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-HP010224502.aspx)

Or if you want use formula
[TRANSPOSE function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/transpose-function-HP010069834.aspx)

Comment: Please, PLEASE don't post link-only answers. What happens in 2 years when your link 404s (or microsoft changes the links, as they often do)?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the INDIRECT function instead. It's a bit tricky but it works :

On the same sheet where you have :

```
Paul
Madrid
23
Victor
Montréal
22
Aude
Copenhague
17
Valérie
Alger
28
```

Add something like (for example on columns B, C, D) :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
etc.
```

It's easy to do with =X+3 formula and drag down formula.

Then, this matrix represent the position of each element in the list, you now just have to use INDIRECT in this way :

```
=INDIRECT("A" & B1)
```

A is the column where are your data
B1 is the position of the first element in the matrix

By draging this formula down and on the right, you will the matrix with the A's elements.

Answer (score 0):

(Using example where source column in `G2:G100` and target table in `H2:J34`.)

Type formula below in first cell of target table (`H2`):

```
=OFFSET($G$2;(ROW()-ROW($2:$2))*3+COLUMN()-COLUMN($H:$H);0)
```

Replacing `$G$2` with first cell of source data, `$2:$2` with first row of target table and `$H:$H` with first column of target table (mind the `$`).

Then just drag formula left and then bottom.

[image]